# Multithreaded EF using MEF

Tags: c#, multithreading, entity-framework, task-parallel-library, mef

I'm writing some sort of scheduler that executes various tasks in parallel. I use MEF as a IoC containter. Because I *know* that sharing a static instance of an ObjectContext is not a good idea, I decided to have an instance per thread. I implemented it like this:

```
[Export(typeof(IDatabaseFactory))]
[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class DatabaseFactory : IDatabaseFactory
{
    [Import]
    public IServiceResolver ServiceResolver { get; set; }

    [ThreadStatic]
    private static IEntityModel _dataContext;

    public IEntityModel Get()
    {
        if (_dataContext == null)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
            Debug.WriteLine(string.Format("Created Context Instance on Thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId));
            Debug.WriteLine("*************************");
        }

        return _dataContext ?? (_dataContext = ServiceResolver.GetService<IEntityModel>());
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("^^^^^^^^Disposing Context^^^^^^^^");

        if (_dataContext != null)
        {
            _dataContext.Dispose();
            _dataContext = null;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the ThreadStatic attribute on the _dataContext field; This code fails with following output:

```
*************************
Created Context Instance on Thread 9
*************************
-- Running Main Thread on thread 9
-- Scheduling servicetask of type ActiveDirectorySynchronisationServiceTask on thread 14
-- Scheduling servicetask of type LogCleanerServiceTask on thread 15
-- Scheduling servicetask of type TranscriptParseServiceTask on thread 17
-- Scheduling servicetask of type MailServiceTask on thread 16
*************************
*************************
Created Context Instance on Thread 15
*************************
Created Context Instance on Thread 17
*************************
Created Context Instance on Thread 16
*************************
*************************
```

With Following errormessage:

```
{"The transaction operation cannot be performed because there are pending requests working on this transaction."}
```

Note that the actual error is not always the same, (sometimes 'Underlying provider failed on open', etc) which convinces me this is a mult threading issue. But I don't see the problem?

Is a connection shared between instances of an ObjectContext? I'm using EF4.0, SQL Server Express 2008

Answer (score 0):

You need MARS (multiple active result sets), http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h32h3abf(v=vs.80).aspx

EF tries to share connections to SQL where possible and this requires the above feature enabled at a connection string level. You only really see this issue when you have mutliple active contexts at the same time (multi-threaded applications or poorly closed contexts)

Comment: It's already set to true, I forgot to mention I'm using SQL Server Express. I will check if MARS is enabled for Express edition, it should be though...

Comment: @pietervp are you using explicit transactions anywhere? (mars should be just fine with express above 2005)

Comment: No transaction, just some simple data crud operations. Now I'm getting a `The type 'xxx.Setting' has been mapped more than once.`. This really smells like EF caching something in a static variable :(

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution for this problem. I added a `[PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.NonShared)]` to the ObjectContext class definition. Probably a shared reference was used by not explicitly defining this attribute.